# How to alert the id of nested div without alerting the id of its parent?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, parent-child, alert

I want to alert the id of the div when I click on it. The code works fine but it also alerts the id of the parent div. How can I avoid that?

Here's the code: **[JSBin Link](http://jsbin.com/awunam/1/edit)**

```
<div id ="parentDiv">
  <div id ="child1"></div>
  <div id ="child2"></div>
</div>
```

JQuery Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('div').click(function(){
   var index = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(index);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `e.stopPropagation()`

```
$('div').click(function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
   var index = $(this).attr("id");
   alert(index);
});
```

Demo `--->` http://jsbin.com/osafuw/1/edit

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `children()` as well

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('div').children().click(function(){
    var index = $(this).attr("id");
    alert(index);
  });
});
```